# Maven: Profiles + Modules

Tags: java, maven, module

I have a project that has some special source folders depending of our clients and we are now going to maven, so I have some questions...

I was wondering if a correct approach to specify which sources will go with each build is defining a special profile for each client, and each profile will have a module in which all client-specific sources will be defined:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>client1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>modules/client1</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I need something that could be described as: "*Ok, if the client is client1, attach this source folders, if client is client2 attach this other folders*". Is there a way to configure Maven to "attach" source folders? Because it seems like we can just override **build-helper-maven-plugin**.

In addition, if I add all the sources in the module I have a problem with my paths, because I need to define my source folders as `<source>../../WEB-INF/src</source` and all my tests go into a mess and it seems like that is a workaround. I need some clues to learn about clean approaches to design my structure.

[Edit]
My folder structure is like this:

```
myApp/plugin1/src
myApp/plugin2/src
myApp/pluginN/src
myApp/WEB-INF/generalSrc
myApp/pom.xml
myApp/clients/myclient1/plugin1/src
myApp/clients/myclient1/plugin2/src
myApp/clients/myclient1/pom.xml
myApp/clients/myclient2/plugin1/src
myApp/clients/myclient2/pom.xml
```

So I want to avoid using things like `<source>../../WEB-INF/generalSrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a parent for a child modules:

```
App  
  ear-module
    pom.xml
  module1    
    pom.xml  
  module2 
    pom.xml  
  module3  
    pom.xml 
  ...
pom.xml
```

Then choose one or more modules to be build by profile:

```
<profile>
   <id>client1</id>
   <modules>
      <module>ear-module</module>
      <module>module1</module>
       ...
   </modules>
</profile>
```

To include only necessary modules in the target package module i.e. ear-module (or war), create profile with the same id similar to:

```
<profile>
  <id>client1</id>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <type>ejb or jar</type>
    </dependency>                   
   </dependencies>
   …
<profile>
```

The second step is more important, but the first will save you time building unused modules.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem that I have with this is my source files are placed like this:

`myApp/myfolder/plugin1/src
myApp/myfolder/plugin2/src
myApp/WEB-INF/generalSrc
myApp/client1/specialFolder/plugin1/src`

So if I create my modules under myApp/client1 the source folders will be something like ../../WEB-INF/generalSrc and it is a problem...

Comment: I meant a solution based only on modules. So every element that has a source folder is a separate module with its own pom.xml. Of course one module (e.g. client1) can have two source folders, but it can be confusing and it's much easier to work on packages. The important point is to avoid manipulations on the source code directories, but to base everything on maven dependencies. But of course, I don't know how far you can modify the project structure, to make it possible.

Comment: I wonder why do you have a source code in the WEB-INF directory? If I understood correctly. Or there are only configuration files?

Comment: Yes, the source code is under WEB-INF. I wonder that too, but that structure was what I found when I came to the company. So I'm trying to bring some order to the code. In the future, I need to move to standard, but in the meantime I need to put Maven to work, to show results :)